# SQL Server is not numeric and not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, numeric

```
select CustomerName from CUSTOMER_TABLE where CustomerId IS NOT NULL
```

How can I get customer name if customer name is not numeric in SQL?

I tried to use `IS NOT NUMERIC`, I get syntax error.

So how can I do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Comment: Why would your customer name be numeric in the first place?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try with [**ISNUMERIC()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx)

**For example, from your query**

```
SELECT CustomerName FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE 
  WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL AND ISNUMERIC(CustomerName) = 0
```

*ISNUMERIC(expr.)* determines whether an expression is a valid numeric type or not.

**Syntax:**

> *ISNUMERIC ( expression )*

Answer (score 10):

The function's name is [`ISNUMERIC`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx):

```
SELECT CustomerName 
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE 
WHERE CustomerId IS NOT NULL 
AND ISNUMERIC( CustomerName ) = 0
```

<kbd>[**Sql-Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2534e/1/0)</kbd>